# Using onClick() defined in separate class in ViewHolder

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView holding CardViews with a favorite button within each card. I would like the favorite button to only be clicked for each specific card. I am currently using a ViewHolder to maintain each of the components in each card and the favorite button is one of those components.

How can I use an onClick() defined in a separate class within the ViewHolder?

Using this code currently only actives the onTouchEvent() for the favoriteButton

```
viewHolder.favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new LikeButtonView(mContext));
```

AppAdapter.java

```
public class AppAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    private List<App> apps;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context mContext;

    public AppAdapter(List<App> apps, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.apps = apps;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        packageManager = this.mContext.getPackageManager();
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        App appObject = apps.get(i);
        viewHolder.appName.setText(appObject.getApplicationName());
        viewHolder.versionNumber.setText(String.valueOf(appObject.getVersionNumber()));
        viewHolder.updateDate.setText(String.valueOf(appObject.getLastUdpateTime()));
        viewHolder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(appObject.getAppIcon());
        viewHolder.appChangelog.setText(appObject.getChangelogText());
        viewHolder.favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new LikeButtonView(mContext));
    }
```

LikeButtonView.java

```
public class LikeButtonView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final DecelerateInterpolator DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    private static final AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator ACCELERATE_DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    private static final OvershootInterpolator OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR = new OvershootInterpolator(4);

    @Bind(R.id.ivStar)
    ImageView ivStar;

    private boolean isChecked;
    private AnimatorSet animatorSet;

    public LikeButtonView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LikeButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public LikeButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public LikeButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_like_button, this, true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        isChecked = !isChecked;
        ivStar.setImageResource(isChecked ? R.drawable.ic_star_rate_on : R.drawable.ic_star_rate_off);

        if (animatorSet != null) {
            animatorSet.cancel();
        }

        if (isChecked) {
            ivStar.animate().cancel();
            ivStar.setScaleX(0);
            ivStar.setScaleY(0);

            animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            ObjectAnimator starScaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ivStar, ImageView.SCALE_Y, 0.2f, 1f);
            starScaleYAnimator.setDuration(350);
            starScaleYAnimator.setStartDelay(0);
            starScaleYAnimator.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator starScaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ivStar, ImageView.SCALE_X, 0.2f, 1f);
            starScaleXAnimator.setDuration(350);
            starScaleXAnimator.setStartDelay(0);
            starScaleXAnimator.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            animatorSet.playTogether(
                    starScaleYAnimator,
                    starScaleXAnimator
            );

            animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    ivStar.setScaleX(1);
                    ivStar.setScaleY(1);
                }
            });

            animatorSet.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ivStar.animate().scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f).setDuration(150).setInterpolator(DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
                setPressed(true);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                boolean isInside = (x > 0 && x < getWidth() && y > 0 && y < getHeight());
                if (isPressed() != isInside) {
                    setPressed(isInside);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                ivStar.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setInterpolator(DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
                if (isPressed()) {
                    performClick();
                    setPressed(false);
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is pointless to pass in that View class as the OnClickListener. And it should be calling the onClick not the onTouch when the button is pressed. Simply create an anonymous class (or lambda) for the setOnClickListener method.

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to use the onClick() method within LikeButtonView.java?

Comment: You would be able to and it would only call the onClick method and nothing more. That's why passing an entire View is pointless.

Comment: So moving the onClick() method to a separate class and then passing that in as viewHolder.favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new SeparateClass(mContext)); would work?

Comment: Yes that should do the trick. It's possible that the Views onClick method conflicted with the onClick method from the OnClickListener interface. Either way you should separate the onClick logic to its own class since there's no need for the View.